# How can I invert colors in a progression?

Tags: colors

How can I invert the colors in a progression for example inverting at a degree of 18% but not fully invert it as most programs do.
Is there any software for that?

As when you look in certain position to the computer screen, as you keep look down up front the colors go through the same process of color invertion. As you look more perpendicularly, more inverted the colors are until they're fully inverted.

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. Are you trying to find a contrasting color? Have you looked at using a HUE, SATURATION, LUMINANCE model for the color instead of R, G, B? What have you tried?

Comment: I want to use a tool that can invert the colors in certain degree but not 100%, as I explained. If you  get your face near the computer screen  and look up to the screen you see that there's a process of image invert as you change the position you're looking the colors get more inverted until they reach color invert fully

Answer (score 0):

```
var progress;

$(selector).css(width: progress);
if(progress == 18)
    $(selector).css(background-color:red);
else
    $(selector).css(background-color:green);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.